# arbor.js custom shape each node

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph, arbor.js

the following code draws an image of an [egg](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/HzrFG/embedded/result/) on an html5 canvas

```js
function init() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {

  // layer1/Path
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100.0, 90.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(100.0, 95.5, 95.5, 100.0, 90.0, 100.0);
  ctx.lineTo(10.0, 100.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.5, 100.0, 0.0, 95.5, 0.0, 90.0);
  ctx.lineTo(0.0, 10.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.0, 4.5, 4.5, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
  ctx.lineTo(90.0, 0.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(95.5, 0.0, 100.0, 4.5, 100.0, 10.0);
  ctx.lineTo(100.0, 90.0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(229, 229, 229)";
  ctx.fill();

  // layer1/Path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10.0, 28.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.0, 37.9, 18.1, 46.0, 28.0, 46.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(37.9, 46.0, 46.0, 37.9, 46.0, 28.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(46.0, 18.1, 37.9, 10.0, 28.0, 10.0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.1, 10.0, 10.0, 18.1, 10.0, 28.0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 191, 30)";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```

I' trying to get arbor.js show the egg as a node I will also be showing other illustrations such as bacon, bread for an interactive restaurant menu. It is meant to go in each node, I beleive? But not quite sure how.

```
particleSystem.eachNode(function(node, pt){
          // node: {mass:#, p:{x,y}, name:"", data:{}}
          // pt:   {x:#, y:#}  node position in screen coords


          // determine the box size and round off the coords if we'll be 
          // drawing a text label (awful alignment jitter otherwise...)
          var w = ctx.measureText(node.data.label||"").width + 6
          var label = node.data.label
          if (!(label||"").match(/^[ \t]*$/)){
            pt.x = Math.floor(pt.x)
            pt.y = Math.floor(pt.y)
          }else{
            label = null
          }

          // clear any edges below the text label
          // ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,.6)'
          // ctx.fillRect(pt.x-w/2, pt.y-7, w,14)


          ctx.clearRect(pt.x-w/2, pt.y-7, w,14)



          // draw the text
          if (label){
            ctx.font = "bold 11px Arial"
            ctx.textAlign = "center"

            // if (node.data.region) ctx.fillStyle = palette[node.data.region]
            // else ctx.fillStyle = "#888888"
            ctx.fillStyle = "#888888"

            // ctx.fillText(label||"", pt.x, pt.y+4)
            ctx.fillText(label||"", pt.x, pt.y+4)
          }
        })          
      },

      resize:function(){
        var w = $(window).width(),
            h = $(window).height();
        canvas.width = w; canvas.height = h // resize the canvas element to fill the screen
        particleSystem.screenSize(w,h) // inform the system so it can map coords for us
        that.redraw()
      },

        initMouseHandling:function(){
        // no-nonsense drag and drop (thanks springy.js)
        selected = null;
        nearest = null;
        var dragged = null;
        var oldmass = 1

        $(canvas).mousedown(function(e){
            var pos = $(this).offset();
            var p = {x:e.pageX-pos.left, y:e.pageY-pos.top}
            selected = nearest = dragged = particleSystem.nearest(p);

            if (selected.node !== null){
            // dragged.node.tempMass = 10000
            dragged.node.fixed = true
            }
            return false
        });
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I realise the solution is right there underneath, but comment with questions if you have trouble with what the code does. I'm guessing your next problem will be how to show different images in the right order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, open up the sample project included with arbor 0.92. In main.js, find the anonymous function attached to `eachNode`:

```
particleSystem.eachNode(function(node, pt){
  // node: {mass:#, p:{x,y}, name:"", data:{}}
  // pt:   {x:#, y:#}  node position in screen coords

  // draw a rectangle centered at pt
  var w = 20
  ctx.fillStyle = (node.data.alone) ? "orange" : "black"
  ctx.fillRect(pt.x-w/2, pt.y-w/2, w/2,w)
})
```

This is the section we need to replace with your 'egg' code. The problem is that you can't just drop your draw function in as it is because it's using *absolute* coordinates, whereas we need to use coordinates relative to where the node is being rendered. Essentially, you need to modify each of the calls in your `draw(ctx)` function to use `pt.x` and `pt.y`, as described in the sample.

**Edit**

Alright, done. Replace the whole block with this:

```
    particleSystem.eachNode(function(node, pt){
      // node: {mass:#, p:{x,y}, name:"", data:{}}
      // pt:   {x:#, y:#}  node position in screen coords

      // draw a rectangle centered at pt

            ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100.0 + pt.x, 90.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(100.0 + pt.x, 95.5 + pt.y, 95.5 + pt.x, 100.0 + pt.y, 90.0 + pt.x, 100.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.lineTo(10.0 + pt.x, 100.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.5 + pt.x, 100.0 + pt.y, 0.0 + pt.x, 95.5 + pt.y, 0.0 + pt.x, 90.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.lineTo(0.0 + pt.x, 10.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.0 + pt.x, 4.5 + pt.y, 4.5 + pt.x, 0.0 + pt.y, 10.0 + pt.x, 0.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.lineTo(90.0 + pt.x, 0.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(95.5 + pt.x, 0.0 + pt.y, 100.0 + pt.x, 4.5 + pt.y, 100.0 + pt.x, 10.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.lineTo(100.0 + pt.x, 90.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(229, 229, 229)";
  ctx.fill();

  // layer1/Path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10.0 + pt.x, 28.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.0 + pt.x, 37.9 + pt.y, 18.1 + pt.x, 46.0 + pt.y, 28.0 + pt.x, 46.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(37.9 + pt.x, 46.0 + pt.y, 46.0 + pt.x, 37.9 + pt.y, 46.0 + pt.x, 28.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(46.0 + pt.x, 18.1 + pt.y, 37.9 + pt.x, 10.0 + pt.y, 28.0 + pt.x, 10.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.1 + pt.x, 10.0 + pt.y, 10.0 + pt.x, 18.1 + pt.y, 10.0 + pt.x, 28.0 + pt.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 191, 30)";
  ctx.fill();
    })
```

[image]

They're not centered as you can see, but hopefully this gives enough of an ideal about how to continue. :)

Comment: Hi Ben thanks so much:) Got it working. I need to add bacon and bread and sausages I guess I need to declare them as variables? I'll look through the rest of the examples to see If I can work it out.

Comment: There are a couple of ways I can think of this working. Try it out for yourself first, then ask a specific question.  
As a hint, this is what *I* think you should do next: move the egg-drawing code from above into it's own function. This function should then be called from eachNode and take `ctx` and `p` as params. Then, update the function to make the image drawn centred around the node, rather than based around the top-left as it is now.  
Once you've done that, it'll be a lot easier to understand how to add new images.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks so much for your time with this, I'll give it a go. If I scramble the eggs I'll post more questions:)

Comment: Hi if i wanted to use a fairly complicated illustration; see http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/SYma7/ could I use the method you describe above without having to add all the x y points to the illustration?

Comment: Hey. Briefly, no, you're always going to need to use the x and y points. There is a workaround (have a proxy class which takes the various canvas commands and adds the correct x/y offset), but a more important question is why use canvas to render these images - you have the output right there, why not create a png and render that?

Comment: I hadn't really considered the png route. Do you mean pngs' as arbor nodes? I still want to keep the ability to create interactive links between the images...

Comment: You can use images as the nodes. The whole thing will still be rendered in canvas, so the links will work. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) for an example of how to render images.

Comment: By 'links' I mean edges, not hyperlinks.

Comment: So is this for a project for your business? Are you a restaurant owner?

Comment: Its just for a bit of design work for my portfolio. I'm interested in the crossover of code and art. I don't think my colorful sausage illustration would go down too well in an actual restaurant menu :)